# PropType not working in any case

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm building a few components and now testing them but I see that the react `PropTypes` are not throwing any errors and I can't seem to find why.

**Example component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Icon } from 'components';

class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        const { icon, position } = this.props;

        console.log(icon, position);

        return (
            <div className='MAIN__section'>
                Test app with dynamic import and resolving
                <Icon icon='tags' />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Test.PropTypes = {
    icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    position: PropTypes.oneOf(['left', 'right']),
    className: PropTypes.string
};

export default Test;
```

**Tried cases**

I updated all my dependencies to the latest versions, ([my `package.json`](https://gist.github.com/nealoke/301a6d61eb6aad9bdae20762ca558df8))

When I provide no `icon` or provide a `position` prop which is not "left" or "right", no errors or warnings are thrown. I verify that PropTypes are being imported correctly by `console.log(PropTypes)`.

Comment: With the latest version of react,`import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri even with that no errors are thrown, I'm on version `15.3.2` :/

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri even after updating to latest react version and using the `prop-types` package, same result.

Comment: Test.propTypes without capital 'p'.

Comment: @ziedhajsalah omg, i'm so stupid, thank you so much <3 your my life saver!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @ziedhajsalah for giving the answer.

it was `componentName.propTypes = {}`, not `componentName.PropTypes = {}`. The capital letter messed it up.